# Are community ads still being displayed?

Tags: support, bug

Has something changed with the way community ads are displayed? Last year our top ads were getting 10+ clicks a day, but so far this year our ads have 1 click *overall*. There was a delay in getting the threads up this year, is this something to do with the changes?

Comment: I've refreshed the main /questions page ~20-30 times, not a single of our ads was shown, all ads shown were for various other SE sites. Or for Area51 proposals. Or for the SE facebook page.

Comment: I've had the same as Arperum. Other SE site ads are showing but not seen a single Arqade one.

Comment: It's worth noting that most of our ads this year are not *technically* compliant, however this does not seem to be the issue: compliant ads are still not being shown, and the only view we do have is on a non-compliant ad.

Comment: [Ads on StackOverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/281524) seem to be getting a similarly negligible number of views.

Comment: Further investigation: I just saw an ad on Mathematics, clicked through to stats and it took me to the 2014 stats page, not 2015. Methinks a part of the community ads magic ritual has been omitted this year.